# conditioon that is necessary and sufficient to ensure $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of integers converges via $\epsilon - N$ logic

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

i want to extend the knowledge the previous question of mine obtained and know when a sequence of integrs does actually converge. i want to work this out using $\epsilon - N$ logic.

my thoughts: this is the same as $\lim \limits_{1 \to \infty} a_n$ we want to have no $N \in \mathbb{N}$ less than $\epsilon$, but i don't know how to consolidate that logic into a condition that is necessary and sufficient for convergence of these integers! any tips are appreciated greaterly thank you

Comment: Integers or real numbers?

Comment: integer sequence

Comment: @JpMcCarthy integer sequence

Comment: They only converge if they are eventually constant. No need for an $\varepsilon$ argument.

Comment: eventually constant?

Comment: A sequence of integers $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots\}$ can only converge if it is eventually constant. That is for all $n$ bigger than some finite $N$ we have $a_i=a$.

Comment: so when an,an+1,an+2 = 12,12,12 for example?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy i just didn't get it based on your previous explaination because you didn't use n or N in ai = a... but i get it, they work different than series then?

Comment: Do you know what a series is?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy just cause you are over twice my age doesnt make me dumb, don't have to be mean... i am just learning this out of personal interests

Comment: @JpMcCarthy sorry didnt think you were going to respond, i take that back! yeah actually on reflection sequence = series

Comment: wait  no a series is a sum of a sequence

Comment: so convergence of a series relies on the reduction of the sequenced terms, and a sequence converges when it simply iterates the one point

Comment: Maybe someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition** $\quad$ $(a_n) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ converges if and only if $\ \ \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \  \exists c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow a_n = c$ (i.e. the sequence is eventually constant)

**Proof** $\quad "\Rightarrow"$ Suppose $(a_n)$ converges to some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. First we must show that $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $c \notin \mathbb{Z}$ then we can let $\epsilon>0$ be the distance from $c$ to the nearest integer. Then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$. But this implies, in particular, that $a_N \notin \mathbb{Z}$, a contradiction. So $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|a_n - c| < 1/2$. Since $c$ is an integer, $c$ is the only integer in the interval $(c-1/2, c+1/2)$. So for $n \geq N$ we must have $a_n = c$.

$"\Leftarrow"$ Suppose that the sequence is eventually constant and equals $c$ for all $n \geq N \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitary. Then $\forall n \geq N$

$$|a_n - c| = |c-c| = 0 < \epsilon,$$

confirming that indeed $a_n \rightarrow c$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.